# Enable Logging to Batch File Commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to enable logging to a batch file which should log all the contents of command prompt including input/output/error. So I have tried something like the following but it results in a empty log file without any contents. It looks, I am missing something. Below is the batch file.

```
@echo off​
SET LOGFILE=C:\Users\xason\Desktop\Logs\logs.txt
call :logit
exit /b 0
​
:logit
set root=C:\ORACLE\ORA_DRIVERS
cd %root% >> %LOGFILE%
UPDATE.EXE E:\class.ora
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
```

Comment: `call :logit >> "%LOGFILE%" 2>&1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log file is empty because you suppressed the output with the command

```
echo off
```

Use `echo on` instead before commands that shall be logged. The command `cd` usually doesn't send anything to stdout. That's why you got an empty file.

Instead of this ping thingy I recommend

```
timeout 6
```

Try this one:

```
@echo off​
SET LOGFILE=C:\Users\xason\Desktop\Logs\logs.txt
echo on
call :logit >>%LOGFILE%
exit /b 0 ​ 

:logit 
set root=C:\ORACLE\ORA_DRIVERS 
cd %root%
UPDATE.EXE E:\class.ora 
@timeout 6 >nul
```

*Edit*: (beacause asked in a comment)
The log file name can also include the date and time. You need to change the SET LOGFILE command appropriately. You can experiment, starting with this:

```
SET LOGFILE=C:\Users\xason\Desktop\Logs\log-%date%-%time%.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to add timestamp (date & time including seconds) to the log file?

Comment: Try `time /t >>%LOGFILE%`.

Comment: but i believe the above wont append timestamp to the log_file name. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Give it a try. That's better than believing.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` command has not `STDOUT`. You probably need to append `STDOUT` of your batch file to a text file. Run your batch file from cmd:

```
batch_file.bat >> "C:\Users\xason\Desktop\Logs\logs.txt"
```

Or, inside your batch file:

```
@echo off​
SET LOGFILE=C:\Users\xason\Desktop\Logs\logs.txt
call :logit >>"%LOGFILE%"
exit /b 0
​
:logit
set root=C:\ORACLE\ORA_DRIVERS
cd %root%
UPDATE.EXE E:\class.ora
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
```

Or even:

```
@echo off​
SET LOGFILE=C:\Users\xason\Desktop\Logs\logs.txt
call :logit
exit /b 0
​
:logit
set root=C:\ORACLE\ORA_DRIVERS
cd %root%
UPDATE.EXE E:\class.ora >> %LOGFILE%
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
```